# How to inherent from multiple Activities with LifeCycle events and event bus support in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, interface, greenrobot-eventbus

I have two activities that both of then extends from a base activity.

i.e.

```
CarActivity{

}

GasCarActivity extends CarActivity{

  function onCreate(){
     registerGasEvent() // so that onLowGasEvent() will work
  }

  function checkGas(){}

  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
  function onLowGasEvent(){

  }
}

ElectricCarActivity extends CarActivity{

  function checkBattery(){}

  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
  function onLowBatteryEvent(){

  }
}
```

Now I need a HybridCarActivity that uses both GasCarActivity and ElectricCarActivity functions and life cycle events.

I'm also using eventbus library, how can I have the Subscribe function of both onLowGasEvent and onLowBatteryEvent in the HybridCarActivity?

What I can do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not support multiple inheritance of **implementation**, but it supports multiple inheritance of **interface**. So, you can implement as many interfaces as you want. 
To avoid duplicates and share code between several classes, you can use delegates.

For example:

1. Interfaces:

```
interface IGas {
  checkGas();
  onLowGasEvent();
}

interface IBattery
  checkBattery();
  onLowBatteryEvent();
}
```

2. implementations of common functionality

```
class GasImpl implements IGas {
  checkGas() {
  ...
  }
  onLowGasEvent() {
  ...
  }
}

class BatteryImpl implements IBattery {
  checkBattery() {
  ...
  }
  onLowBatteryEvent() {
  ...
  }
}
```

3. Activities (pay attention to implementaion setion):

```
class GasCar extends Car implements IGas {
  IGas mGasImpl = new GasImpl();   // create it in your own code, or inject to inverse dependencies, etc.

  checkGas() {
    mGasImpl.checkGas();
  }

  onLowGasEvent() {
    mGasImpl.onLowGasEvent();
  }
}

class BatteryCar extends Car implements IBattery {
  IBattery mBatteryImpl;   

  checkBattery() {
    mBatteryImpl.checkGas();
  }

  onLowBatteryEvent() {
    mBatteryImpl.onLowBatteryEvent();
  }
}
```

4. And then your `HybridCar` will be something like this:

```
class HybridCar extends Car implements IGas {
  IGas mGasImpl;
  IBattery mBatteryImpl;   

  checkGas() {
    mGasImpl.checkGas();
  }
  checkBattery() {
    mBatteryImpl.checkBattery();
  }
}
```

5. If you want to work with `EventBus`, you should keep subscribers as an Activity interface - but delegate it's implementation to the handlers as well. So, in the `HybridActivity`:

```
  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
  function onLowGasEvent(){
     mGasImpl.onLowGasEvent();
  }

  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
  function onLowBatteryEvent(){
    mBatteryImpl.onLowBatteryEvent();
  }
```

If `onLow...Event` requires `Context`, update interface methods to pass it as a parameter.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Because Activity is special, it comes with activity life cycle events. So how do we inherent that in this case?

Comment: @CodingTT, I'm not sure if I understand you problem fully. Could you provide some example?

Comment: I updated the question, I think that has more info for the question

Comment: @CodingTT, thanks, it's much clearer now. I have very low experience with `EventBus`, but I think, the suggested approach is still possible. Please, review the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have multiple inheritance.  You are going to have to make the Car object have the shared methods that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kristy Whesh suggest, Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance...but there are interfaces!

Just do something like this:

-Create two interfaces: One for gas car and the other for Electric car.

-Your hybrid car implements these two interfaces, so you have the two funcions that you need to ovveride.

-Your old car classes implements the correct interface according to their type.

Hope this help or give you some hint.

Cheers